# program hangs during execution of shell command given via piping and fork

Tags: c, shell, pipe, fork, execvp

I am not sure why I am hanging here.  As far as I can tell I have piped and forked correctly, and when I checked the data in the arrays it was good.  Yet when I try to run a command like "ls -l | grep total" it hangs.  Can anyone help me?

When I run a command with no piping involved, its fine.  But when I try to implement the piping part, it hangs.  The weird thing is, this was working for me before I broke everything up into separate functions.  I assume I am making an error somewhere, but I'm just not seeing what it is.  I tried to keep everything similar to how I had it before I refactored my code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define MAX_BUF_SZ 1024
#define MAX_ARGS 10

bool checkForPipe(const char *string);
bool checkForRedirect(const char *string);
void tokenizeInput(char * string,
                   char ** l_array,
                   char **m_array,
                   char **r_array,
                   bool pipey,
                   bool redirect,
                   int *status);
void createArguments(char *string, char **arg_array);
void executeCommand(int status, char **l_array, char **m_array, char **r_array);

int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    bool is_pipe = false;
    bool is_redirect_out = false;
    bool is_exit = false;
    int exec_status = 0;                     //Will determine how to execute execvp()
    char *l_args[MAX_ARGS] = {NULL};
    char *m_args[MAX_ARGS] = {NULL};
    char *r_args[MAX_ARGS] = {NULL};


    ptr = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);

    while(!is_exit)
    {
        // Diplay prompt
        char cur_dir[MAX_BUF_SZ];
        getcwd(cur_dir, MAX_BUF_SZ);
        printf("SHELL:%s$ ", cur_dir);

        fgets(ptr, MAX_BUF_SZ, stdin);
        is_pipe = checkForPipe(ptr);
        is_redirect_out = checkForRedirect(ptr);

        if(strcmp(ptr, "exit\n") == 0)
        {
            is_exit = true;
        }

        tokenizeInput(ptr,
                      l_args,
                      m_args,
                      r_args,
                      is_pipe,
                      is_redirect_out,
                      &exec_status);
        executeCommand(exec_status, l_args, m_args, r_args);

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ARGS; i++)
        {
            l_args[i] = NULL;
            m_args[i] = NULL;
            r_args[i] = NULL;
        }

    }

    return 0;

}

bool checkForPipe(const char *string)
{
    return strchr(string, '|') != NULL;
}

bool checkForRedirect(const char *string)
{
    return strchr(string, '>') != NULL;
}

void tokenizeInput(char *string,
                  char **l_array,
                  char **m_array,
                  char **r_array,
                  bool pipey,
                  bool redirect,
                  int *status)
{

    // No pipes or redirects given by user
    if(!pipey && !redirect)
    {
        char main_str[1024];
        strcpy(main_str, string);

        //initialize argument array
        createArguments(main_str, l_array);

        *status = 1;

    }

    //A single pipe given by user
    else if(pipey && !redirect)
    {
        char main_str[1024];
        char pipe_str[1024];
        strcpy(main_str, string);


        char *token = strchr(main_str, '|');
        *token = '\0';
        token++;
        while(*token == ' ')
        {
            token++;
        }

        strcpy(pipe_str, token);

        //initialize argument arrays
        createArguments(main_str, l_array);
        createArguments(pipe_str, r_array);

        *status = 2;

    }

    // A single redirect given by user
    else if(!pipey && redirect)
    {
        char main_str[1024];
        char pipe_str[1024];
        strcpy(main_str, string);

        char *token = strchr(main_str, '>');
        *token = '\0';
        token++;
        while(*token == ' ')
        {
            token++;
        }

        strcpy(pipe_str, token);

        //Initialize argument arrays
        createArguments(main_str, l_array);
        createArguments(pipe_str, r_array);

        *status = 3;

    }
    else if(pipey && redirect)
    {
        // declare some strings
        char copy_str[MAX_BUF_SZ];
        char main_str[MAX_BUF_SZ];
        char pipe_str[MAX_BUF_SZ];
        char redirect_str[MAX_BUF_SZ];

        //make copy of the readonly string
        strcpy(copy_str, string);
        char *token = strtok(copy_str, "|>");

        //create the main string
        strcpy(main_str, copy_str);

        //create pipe string
        token = strtok(NULL, "|>");
        while(*token == ' ')
        {
            token++;
        }
        strcpy(pipe_str, token);

        //create redirect string
        token = strtok(NULL, "|>");
        while(*token == ' ')
        {
            token++;
        }
        strcpy(redirect_str, token);

        //initialize argument arrays
        createArguments(main_str, l_array);
        createArguments(pipe_str, m_array);
        createArguments(redirect_str, r_array);

        *status = 4;

    }
}

void createArguments(char *string, char **arg_array)
{
    char *token;
    char copy_str[MAX_BUF_SZ];
    strcpy(copy_str, string);

    int i = 0;
    for(token = strtok(copy_str, " \n"), i = 0; token; token = strtok(NULL, " \n" ), ++i)
    {
        arg_array[i] = token;
    }

    
}

void executeCommand(int status, char **l_array, char **m_array, char **r_array)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t cpid_1;
    pid_t cpid_2;

    // No Pipes or Redirects
    if(status == 1)
    {

        cpid_1 = fork();

        if(cpid_1 < 0)
        {
            printf("Failed to fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  //Error forking
        }
        if(cpid_1 == 0)
        {
            if(execvp(l_array[0], l_array) == -1)
            {
                printf("failed to execute command");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }
    else if(status == 2)
    {

        if(pipe(fd) == -1)
        {
            printf("failed to pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     // Failed to create pipe
        }
        cpid_1 = fork();
        
        if(cpid_1 < 0)
        {
            printf("failed to fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     //Failed to fork
        }

        if(cpid_1 == 0)
        {
            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            execvp(l_array[0], l_array);
        }

        cpid_2 = fork();
        if(cpid_2 < 0)
        {
            printf("failed to fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);        // Failed to fork
        }

        if(cpid_2 == 0)
        {
            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            execvp(r_array[0], r_array);
        }

    }
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);

        waitpid(cpid_1, NULL,0);
        waitpid(cpid_2, NULL, 0);

}
```

Comment: Have you run it through a debugger and checked where it’s hanging?

Comment: @pion so Valgrind returns no leaks, and gdb complains about my first call to waitpid()

Answer (score 0):

In `tokenizeInput()` you are setting `*status` to a possible integer value between `1` and `4`. But in `executeCommand()` you’re only handling the cases where `status` is `1` or `2`. The “pipes + redirects” case is `status=4` and you aren’t handling that case in `executeCommand()`. Hence you’re hanging in `waitpid()` – nothing has been forked.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  I know I am not handling that part quite yet.  However, status for "ls -l | grep" should be 2 not 4 so I don't see why I am hanging.  I can check to verify its 2 and not 4 though.

Comment: Ok I checked it, and status being passed to execute command for those particular arguments is '2'.

Comment: My mistake, I didn’t look closely enough. So, since you are in gdb, have you done a line-by-line step through `executeCommand()` and examined your local variables at each point to confirm that they all have their expected values?

Comment: No.  I looped through the arguments arrays to see what was in them but it wasn't helpful.  They were all normal values.  I guess I will try gdp step through next.

Comment: I stepped through the code in gdb... it seemed to just go passed execute command without the hangup and back around to the start of my while loop.  I was monitoring variables and stuff and didn't notice anything out of the ordinary other than the fact that my grep stuff never happened.

Comment: Did you make sure to use “step into” (`s`) rather than “step over” (`n`)?

Comment: Yeah, took forever.  it goes from line 286 which is if(cpid2 == 0), straight to line 67 which is after executeCommand()

Comment: But there are no warnings or anything glaring that I can see.

Comment: Did you make sure to compile with optimization off (`-Og`) and debugging symbols enabled (`-g`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228401/discussion-between-pion-and-cemetery-gates).